# Modifying return type of method based on parameter of a calling method with aspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I need to modify return type of a method of a legacy code using aspectj.

```
class MyClass{
   public void processTracker(TrackInfo trackInfo) {        
     if (isValid(this.getStatus()) {
        process(trackInfo);
     }
   }

  boolean isValid(Status status){
   ...
  } 
}
```

I want  `isValid` method to return true/false by some other logic based state of `TrackInfo` object (which is passed parameter to `processTracker` method)

aspecting  `processTracker` method will give me paramaeter but won't give option to modify return value of isValid

```
@Around("execution(* MyClass.processTracker(..))
```

aspecting `isValid` won't give me access to parameter `trackInfo`

2 aspects it's not possible as this code runs in multi-threaded...
I am not using Spring and can't add custom annotation to the legacy code.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your question is hard to understand, maybe because your command of English is not particularly good. In particular, I have no idea why you think that multi-threading should be any issue here. Maybe you can explain that in a little more detail.

Anyway, I am offering you two AOP solutions here:

1. Just call `process(TrackInfo)` directly from the aspect if the `if` condition really is the whole logic in `processTracker(TrackInfo)`, as indicated by your sample code. Semantically, you just **replace the whole logic** of the intercepted method.
2. If there is in fact more logic within `processTracker(TrackInfo)` and your sample code was over-simplified, like a surgeon you need to cut with a finer knive and apply what in AOP terms is often referenced to as a **wormhole pattern**.

**Application + helper classes:**

Because your sample code is incomplete, I had to guess and make up an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which next time I expect you to do as it is actually your job, not mine.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public enum Status {
    VALID, INVALID
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class TrackInfo {
  private String info;

  public TrackInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
  }

  public String getInfo() {
    return info;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "TrackInfo(" + info + ")";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static de.scrum_master.app.Status.*;

public class MyClass {
  private Status status = VALID;

  public void processTracker(TrackInfo trackInfo) {
    if (isValid(getStatus()))
      process(trackInfo);
  }

  public void process(TrackInfo trackInfo) {
    System.out.println("Processing " + trackInfo);
  }

  private Status getStatus() {
    if (status == VALID)
      status = INVALID;
    else
      status = VALID;
    return status;
  }

  boolean isValid(Status status) {
    return status == VALID;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.processTracker(new TrackInfo("normal"));
    myClass.processTracker(new TrackInfo("whatever"));
    myClass.processTracker(new TrackInfo("special"));
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am just alternating the validity from invalid to valid and back with every call, just to get different results when running the main method.

The console log is:

```
Processing TrackInfo(whatever)
```

So far, so good. No let us assume that if the `TrackInfo` matches the string "special", we want to always assume the validity check evaluates to true.

**1.) Aspect replacing logic of `processTracker(TrackInfo)`**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.MyClass;
import de.scrum_master.app.TrackInfo;

@Aspect
public class SimpleAspect {
  @Around("execution(* de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.processTracker(..)) && args(trackInfo) && target(myClass)")
  public void modifyValidityCheck(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, TrackInfo trackInfo, MyClass myClass) throws Throwable {
    if (trackInfo.getInfo().equalsIgnoreCase("special")) {
      // Kick off processing based on some special logic
      myClass.process(trackInfo);
    }
    else {
      // Proceed normally
      thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
  }
}
```

Here we do not need to know what the validity check would evaluate to but just call `process(TrackInfo)` directly if needed. The log output changes to:

```
Processing TrackInfo(whatever)
Processing TrackInfo(special)
```

**2.) Wormhole pattern solution**

Here we actually pull the `TrackInfo` from the calling method `processTracker(TrackInfo)` as context information into `isValid(Status status)` so we can directly modify the validity check result if necessary.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import static de.scrum_master.app.Status.*;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import de.scrum_master.app.Status;
import de.scrum_master.app.TrackInfo;

@Aspect
public class WormholePatternAspect {
  @Pointcut("execution(* de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.processTracker(..)) && args(trackInfo)")
  public static void processTracker(TrackInfo trackInfo) {}

  @Pointcut("execution(* de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.getStatus())")
  public static void getStatus() {}

  @Around("getStatus() && cflow(processTracker(trackInfo))")
  public Status modifyValidityCheck(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint, TrackInfo trackInfo) throws Throwable {
    if (trackInfo.getInfo().equalsIgnoreCase("special")) {
      // Return true based on some special logic
      return VALID;
    }
    else {
      // Proceed normally
      return (Status) thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
  }
}
```

The console log is the same as with the first aspect, but if there is more logic within `processTracker(TrackInfo)`, the rest of it would also be executed, not cut off (replaced) as in the first aspect.

Take your pick. I recommend to go with the simpler solution if applicable. The wormhole pattern is elegant but more difficult to understand and requires runtime call-stack analysis due to `cflow()`, thus it should be slightly slower as well.

Comment: Sorry for bad question but you understood it perfectly . I do have more logic within processTracker, but I still can understand how you modify the validity via Wormhole pattern solution

Comment: Then I would appreciate if you accepted my answer (click on the check mark near the answer's vote counter) in order to close the question.